# Allow toast to be accessible from another class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a toast from another class.

In class 1 I have the toast method:

```
public static void textToast(String textToDisplay) 
{
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = textToDisplay;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER, 50, 50);
    toast.show();
}
```

I am trying to call this toast from another class but when I make the method static, it says cannot make a static reference to this method `getApplicationContext().`

I access it by using `class2.textToast("");`

Any advice on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10788181/884674 this is the perfect solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to provide a method which should be valid for different contexts (e.g. activities), pass this context as parameter.

```
public static void textToast(String textToDisplay, Context context)  { ... }
```

If you want to call this method from nested inner classes (as is often the case), you can use `this` as context

```
public void textToast(String textToDisplay) {
    ...
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(OuterClass.this, text, duration);
    ...
}
```

(or implement `textToast` in the outer class and call it via `OuterClass.this.textToast` from the nested inner class)

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't seem to work either. The other class is not an activity nor is it nested. It is just a simple class which contains the logic for the main activity. When I put Context context in the parameter this does not allow me to use textToast("") displayed as a string in the main activity. Thanks

Comment: You need a `Context` to display a toast. So no matter where you want to call your method, you have to provide a context - which is the usually the activity. From your activity, you could call `WhatEverClass.textToast("", this)`... and if you want to call your method from non-contexts, the only way is to define a context before using the method...

Comment: Okay thanks, in the main class with the activity this works with this. In the simple class I create an new method with context and when I put ("", this) it says this cannot be used in a static context, is there anything else I can use instead of this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void FlesmynToast(Activity fActivity, String fMessage) {
    LayoutInflater fInflater = fActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    View fView = fInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast (ViewGroup) fActivity.findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

    ImageView image = (ImageView) fView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    TextView fText = (TextView) fView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    fText.setText(fMessage);

        // Toast...
    Toast fToast = new Toast(fActivity.getApplicationContext());
    fToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    fToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    fToast.setView(fView);
    fToast.show();
}
```