# Using Toast in a external class

Tags: android, toast

I have a class that controls my app logic apart from the one who extends Activity, and its declared inside this last one.

I would like to know if there is a way to use toast on that class.

I tried extending that class with Activity and sending the context in his constructor but it didn't work.

**EDIT:**

Here you have the code of how I pass the context in the constructor:

```
GameController newgame = new GameController(getApplicationContext());

public GameController(Context _context)
{       
    //...       
    context = _context;
}

Toast.makeText(context, "You can't bet this amount, the minimun bet is: " + minimun_bet, 2).show();
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
05-29 10:58:06.230: E/AndroidRuntime(5753): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Comment: can you paste the your constructor code

Comment: Whichever way your logic control class is created, it must be instantiated from an Activity of some sort.  So add a `Context` member to your control class and pass `this` to its constructor from the activity.

Comment: The code I use into the constructor is just added.

Answer (score 3):

Toast only need to use Context to show. All you need to do is pass the Context to this class and it all will be fine. I do this all the time for all of my custom class. If you could share how you implement/call this passing Context in constructor, we could help pointing out.

Basically, it's something like this:

```
public MyClass{
    private Context context;
    public MyClass(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    private void alert(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(this.context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Now, what you wanna do is checking to see if that Context is valid or not when you pass into it. There's so many instances when I accidentally use getBaseContext instead of getApplicationContext and that cause problem. But in fact, you can just pass your Activity in and cast it as Context without any problem.

Comment: I tried this way but I get a runtime error.
You can see the code in the first post.

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree. The error message stated that you are calling Toast.show() from non-UI thread. I hope you are actually doing the toast.show() in some sort of method and not directly inside the class. I think you probably has a thread or maybe the GameController is a thread/runnable itself. That will explain the error. If you move the toast.show() into the constructor and still getting error then my guess would be correct as far as I know. Maybe you have runOnUIThread method in the class you extend or inside the thread. Try to check for that.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to call toast.show() in a non-UI **class**, but not in a different thread.
Actually, I create an instance ot GameController in my main (and UI) class, that is what starts a thread. And then when the instance of GameController does his work, and needs it, it creates a toast and make show. There is the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ClassName {        
    public ClassName(Activity _activity) {
            Toast.makeText(_activity, "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

you can use it as ClassName(YourActivity.this);

Comment: I get the same runtime error using this way:
05-29 11:11:05.027: E/AndroidRuntime(5862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 0):

The class should not need to be extended from Activity, but you would need to somehow pass it a context to use.  This could be an Activity context or the Application context.

Just make sure it does not hold onto the context forever.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** it worked for me

In your Activity

Context context= new yourclass().getAndSetMyContext(Activity.this);

In your Class
private static Context c;

```
public  Context getAndSetMyContext(Context c) {
    this.c = c;
    return this.c;
}
```

in Method where you need the Toast just use

Toast.makeText(c,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();